# Can't edit background image in iframe

Tags: css, iframe

I have a page with the body tag and the HTML tag styled with a css background image. It is a SVG. Now I noticed that when I go to a page that has an IFRAME in it that holds our tiny wysywyg editor in it. The frames body tags ALSO has out site background image and you can't read what you type in it lol. I have tried everything but I can't get the frames background-image to NONE unless I change it for the whole site. to

Comment: Can you add some relevant code showing exactly how you are declaring the background of the site?

Comment: What happens if you add an `id` attribute to your iframe then style it in CSS? `#myiframe {background: white;}`